# How to write expensive summaries less often in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensorflow model. In it, I have different summaries. Some, such as loss and accuracy and inexpensive, and I want to write them often. Others, like accuracy on the test set are more expensive to calculate and I want to write them say, 100 times less often than normal summaries. What is the best way to implement it in tensorflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of merging all summaries with [`merge_all()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/merge_all), you create a few different groups of summaries with [`merge()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/merge) and then write them with different frequency. Something like this:

```
s1 = tf.summary.image(...)
s2 = tf.summary.scalar(...)
s3 = tf.summary.histogram(...)
s4 = tf.summary.audio(...)

summary_expensive = tf.summary.merge([s1, s4])
summary_cheap     = tf.summary.merge([s2, s3])

# open a session `sess`
# init variables
# create a writer `writer`
for i in xrange(many_steps):
  summary1 = sess.run(summary_cheap)
  writer.add_summary(summary1, i)

  if i % 100 == 0:
     summary2 = sess.run(summary_expensive)
     writer.add_summary(summary2, i)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov you are welcome. Actually TF documentation and examples are pretty good and in my opinion worse the time to read. They explain many concepts in reasonable details.

Comment: I try reading it and finding answers there but not always succeed at it. Will try to go through it to improve my understanding.